# Popup empty (no items), after click on Site actions / More options

Tags: survey

I am using sharepoint 2010. When I try to create a survey I try to do the following steps:

1) Click on site actions

2) Click on more options

Here I see no items.
[image]

Also this scenario is not working:

1) Click on site actions

2) View all site content

3) Create

Here I got this error
[image]

What do I need to do or what is the problem?

UPDATE:

I see in the uls log the following error:

```
Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.  Please close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from them, but not before.  Stack trace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.SharePointClientJs_Register(Page page)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.InitJs_Register(Page page)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterForControl(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, String uiVersion)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterOnDemand(Page page, String strKey, String strFile, Boolean localizable)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterCore(Page page, Boolean defer)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.RegisterOWSScript(Page page, SPWeb web)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage.FormOnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at ASP._layouts_addgallery_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)    
 at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

I see also the url which is loading in the popup:
http://mywebsite.com/_layouts/AddGallery.aspx?IsDlg=1

Comment: Check the ULS logs for more information is the first step (as most of the times)

Comment: I did, but cannot find some related logging..This page is working: _layouts/create.aspx. But the popup should also work. I see it is silverlight which is showing the items.